# How can I request a url using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, post, get

I am quite new in this area.
I need to find out how to make a request to my solr server using Ajax 
How can I give a url(my solr server's url) in request
Any body know how to deal with this?
How can i make a request to the below mentioned url

```
http://mysite:8080/solr/select/?q=%2A%3A%2A&version=2.2&start=0&rows=100&indent=on
```

See here: Corrected the Code Snippet as below

```
function getProductIds() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) console.dir(xmlhttp);
        else alert('no response');
        var ajaxURL = "http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=*:*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=100&indent=on";
        xmlhttp.open("GET", ajaxURL, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

This is my code, it always showing "no response"
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   url: "url path",
   context: document.body
   }).done(function(data) {
      alert(data);
});
```

This one also will work.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to prepare the URL before sending in the request first get the URl using javascript and then encode it to ajax format like below

```
var URL = location.href;
var ajaxURL = encodeURIComponent(URL);
xmlhttp.open("GET",ajaxURL,true);
```

after reading your question clearly it seemed it is a static URL hence you can do below

```
var URL = "http://localhost:8080/blah blah blah";
xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,true);
```

Are you sure it is Get request. because get requests are most of the time cached. also log the response object into Firebug console and inspect the object to know more. Since you get no response that means the server did not send you anything for the request you made.

Comment: @Nikhil so did it work. I am not resting until it works :D btw if it answered please click the tick mark below voting controls

Comment: Ya it get worked, But I didn't get any response from server. The code which i used can find above.
It get worked when i use the url in my browser, I got xml response in my browser
But while using it in Ajax I am not getting any responses
Please help me

Comment: @Nikil this is because i have changed the code and you need to inspect the Firebug console to view the response. If the response is present then remove this part `console.dir(xmlhhtp)` and replace with your logic

Comment: Hi Deeptechtons,
Alert box is showing no response and In firebug I am getting '200' as response,

Comment: @Nikhil `Since you get no response that means the server did not send you anything for the request you made.` i already hinted, your server isn't sending response hence you get no response.

Comment: But when i use the url in my browser, it gave response in xml format.

Comment: Do the test system have external Ip address i can access. Enable HTTP on your system and PM me the Ip address

Answer (score 1):

I'm just now working on XMLHttpRequests to solr as well and I was stuck with what seems like an identical problem. I too am quite new at this. However, the problem for me was that of *same origin policy*. Firefox seems to give very little feedback when this problem occurs. Chrome at least give you a error message (most of the time?).

In Chrome you can get around this, but only for development purposes, by starting it with the ['--disable-web-security'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy) command line option.

I'm yet to find a good workaround for this problem for Solr. In general you avoid the restriction by only using requests with relative paths, but [that doesn't seem possible when doing a request to another port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767443/can-i-use-xmlhttprequest-on-a-different-port-from-a-script-file-loaded-from-that).

[Ways to circumvent the policy (I haven't had time to study this too much yet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Ah, now I see that your problem was resolved down the comments. Well, I might help someone else with this..