# ajax and nodejs

Tags: ajax, node.js

Is possible to send ajax request from apache server (e.g : http://localhost/myscript) to node js without any problems ??

I try that and it's work perfectly but it's not working in mozilla only IE.

my ajax :

```
$.ajax({
url : "http://localhost:3000/test_ajax",
type: "GET",
success : function(data){
    alert(data);
}
});
```

my nodejs server :

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/test_ajax', function(req, res){
res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

is possible to use this in my projects without problemes?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767443/can-i-use-xmlhttprequest-on-a-different-port-from-a-script-file-loaded-from-that

Comment: I want solution not other question :S

Comment: Have you looked at the other question and its accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to using normal XHR (aka Ajax) in that case. See: [Can I use XMLHttpRequest on a different port from a script file loaded from that port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767443/can-i-use-xmlhttprequest-on-a-different-port-from-a-script-file-loaded-from-that)

You'll have to either use JSONP (which allows cross-domain data retrieval)

```
$.ajax({…, dataType: 'jsonp'});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Other to set up a proxy on your main domain to do the conversion between the two ports. They are some projects doing that already:

- PHP, https://github.com/hugeinc/ajax-proxy
- Python (Django), http://httpproxy.yvandermeer.net/
- …

Comment: You dont need JSONP, you can just do CORS manually by setting the headers correctly

Comment: [CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) aren't available on every browsers are they? http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors

Comment: IE6/7 and opera fail. You will need to do feature detection or shimming for IE8/9